# Ensure that an IntegerField never goes below a certain value in Django

Tags: django

I'd like to make sure that an integer field in my model never gets below a certain amount, is there a way to add some sort of constraint in Django? Or do I need to add a `max()` around all places I check for the value?

Comment: Have a look at [django-check-contraints](https://github.com/theju/django-check-constraints), maybe?

Comment: Besides the validation on Django, you should also consider adding a database constrain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

- First one in [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).
- The second one in the [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) (for the model forms).

**updated**

If you don't use forms, then you can overwrite save() method or write code in pre-save signal:

```
pre_save.connect(yourModel_pre_save, sender = yourModel ) 

def yourModel_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instance.some_value > some_other_value: 
         raise ValidationError('Value to high')
```

don't forget to enclose save() method into a `try` clause:

```
m = yourModel.objects.get( pk = 1 )
try:
    m.save()
except ValidationError, e:
        import itertools
        errors = list( itertools.chain( *e.message_dict.values() ) )
```

If you don't like signals, then overwrite save method:

```
class yourModel(model.Model):
    description=models.CharField()
    some_value=models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.some_value > some_other_value: 
             raise ValidationError('Value to high') 
        super(yourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not using forms, I thought that those validations were only for forms. Am I missing something?

Comment: Form validation and model validation are for forms. Rewrite save() or writing pre-save() signal runs at level model. I have updated my post.